# How i can push array $b to array $a ? i want result like $c

Tags: php, arrays

Here is first array

```
$a = array(
    'Acer' => array(
            'Image' => 'lg_acer.gif',
            'Link' => array
                (
                     'acer-phones-1.php',
                )
        ),
    'Allview' => array(
            'Image' => 'lg_allview2.gif',
            'Link' => array(
                    'allview-phones-1.php',
                )
        )
);
```

Here is second array

```
$b =array(
    array(
            'acer-phones-2.php',
            'acer-phones-3.php',
        ),
     array(
        )
);
```

I want result like this

```
$c = array(
    'Acer' => array(
            'Image' => 'lg_acer.gif',
            'Link' => array(
                    'acer-phones-1.php',
                    'acer-phones-2.php',
                    'acer-phones-3.php',
                )
        ),
    'Allview' => array(
            'Image' => 'lg_allview2.gif',
            'Link' => array(
                    'allview-phones-1.php',
                )
        )
);
```

Here 2 arrays. I want to make a array by combining array $a and array $b which will be like array $c.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

First make a copy of the whole array, then use `array_merge` to combine `$b` with the appropriate sub-array in `$c`.

```
$c = $a;
$c['Acer']['Link'] = array_merge($c['Acer']['Link'], $b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array_merge() is what you need. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp for more info

Comment: How does `array_combine` help with this? He's not creating an associative array with keys from one of the arrays.

Comment: My bad, merge was what I was looking for